# How to get the pixels values and coordinates of the objects unside bounding boxes - Yolov5?

Tags: object, pixel, yolo, bounding-box, yolov5

I'm trying to get the pixels values and coordinates of the objects inside the bounding boxes of yolov5, Is there any method to do it ? Thanks